# Mail() doesn't set From header with postfix

Tags: php, postfix-mta

I am trying to send email with `mail()` it works but even if I set `From: email <name>` it is sent with the original email of my server.

Is there anyway to solve this? I have debian with postfix

Comment: php's build in mail function is *very* under powered, use a third party library and all will be well. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ is one i like

Comment: no i just installed postfix to get rid of those lib... (they are not good at all for sending batch-email). And I think the problem here is with the postfix config not php

Comment: i use phpmailer to send thousands of email a day (legit-work). mail is about 10 times slower for bulk mail

Comment: that's it's pretty impossibile because mail just add the email to the queue email. the mail daemon will take care of emails later. mail() can't be slower than anything.. maybe you are on windows

Comment: a direct socket connection kept open to the smtp sever is much faster.

Comment: from the manual:

"It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient. "

Comment: that's for windows again. on linux you can't setup a SMTP. Anyway please stop the OT. If you think mail is slower it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-f mail@mail.com` to the last param of `mail()` and it will work.